# Best way to deal with component terminating intents in MVI

Tags: android, architecture, mosby

I´m a huge fan of the MVI pattern, that I have recently implemented in one of my android projects, using mosby. There is one problem I haven´t figured out so far how the best way would be to deal with it. It is about finishing intents, eg. a 'save and finish activity/fragment' intent, that would be triggered by back press, where the component is terminated right after the user action, but something needs to be done in the interactor before that. 
I tried it the usual way by observing and saving interactor (the intent is fired by a PublishSubject, that fires in onBackPressed) and returning a (irrelevant) viewstate. But it seems that the component and observable chain are killed too fast, save method in interactor is not called.
So it somehow needs to be a blocking observable intent. Any suggestions how to deal with that?

```
private val saveSubject = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()

override fun onBackPressed() = saveSubject.onNext(Unit)

val saveIntent = intent(View::saveIntent).switchMap { interactor.save() }
```

Comment: It is possible that this is caused by a internal Mosby bug, see here: https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/242

This should be fixed in `3.1.1`. Current version is `3.1.0` but `3.1.1-SNAPSHOT` is available. Check the readme.